# Is there a way to increase the in-game log window font size?

Tags: retro-pixel-castles

In [Retro Pixel Castles](http://retropixelcastles.com/index.php?/page/index.html), the font in the in-game log window is very small. I'm specifically talking about the upper-left of the screen, shown here:

[image: Screenshot of the UI area I'm talking about]

Is there a way to increase the size of that font?